# Update all values in a map using values from another map (Elixir)

Tags: hashmap, elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I update all values in a map, using the values from corresponding keys of another map?
For example I have the two maps bellow:

```
map = %{"December 2021" => 0, "November 2021" => 0, "October 2021" => 0}
map_2 = %{"December 2021" => 7, "November 2021" => 6}
```

And I want to update all values from map with the corresponding values from map_2, so in the end map = %{"December 2021" => 7, "November 2021" => 6, "October 2021" => 0}

I have tried:

```
Enum.map(map_2, fn {key, value} -> %{map | k => v} end)
```

I have also tried the code above with other functions like Map.update!/3 and similar ones, but they all return a list with maps for each iteration of Enum.map.

Does someone have any idea on how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to accomplish this is to use the [`Map.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/2) function, which does exactly this:

```
Map.merge(map, map_2)
```

This will merge all key-value pairs from `map_2` into `map`.

Of course, you could write a custom version of it using `Enum.reduce/3` as well as suggested by @zwippie, but this would be less efficient and more verbose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's very legible and I don't know how I haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/Enum.html#reduce/3). Reduce here means to reduce a collection to a single value. The collection to reduce here is `map_2`. The initial/single value you start with is the original collection `map`. The output is a modification of the initial value.

In this example, every key/value of `map_2` is passed to a function that also expects an accumulator `acc`. `acc` is initialized with the initial value `map` (the second argument of Enum.reduce). In this case, every value of `map_2` is added to `map`:

```
map = %{"December 2021" => 0, "November 2021" => 0, "October 2021" => 0}
map_2 = %{"December 2021" => 7, "November 2021" => 6}

Enum.reduce(map_2, map, fn {key, value}, acc ->
  Map.put(acc, key, value)
end)

#> %{"December 2021" => 7, "November 2021" => 6, "October 2021" => 0}
```

If you want different behavior, for example don't add values from `map_2` with keys that are non-existent in `map`: try to change the reducer function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly. But in my opinion sabiwara's solution is simpler.